# FindElementsBy id for username and password

Tags: selenium

I've started learning selenium web driver. I've come across an issue. When I navigate to my URI, I come across an windows authentication window before I can access my web page. Im using C# for the scripting. Ive got the code that I should be using:

```
            // Get the page elements
            var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("usr");
            var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("pwd");
            var loginButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Login']");

            // Type user name and password
            userNameField.SendKeys("admin");
            userPasswordField.SendKeys("12345");
```

But this is only good if you have a normal login page. I can't get to the elements or get the Fire Path id as the window authentication pop will not let me. Can someone please help me with this. How do I automate this process

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have a way to handle this by passing username and password inside URL like the following:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(https://<username>:<password>@<URL>");
```

e.g.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(https://auth_user1:userpassword1@www.google.com");
```

Hope this helps!